# Pass parameter from shell script to c program

Tags: c, bash, shell

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
GNU bash, version 4.2.37
```

Hello,

I have the following bash script that I want to pass string parameter to my c program. I tried using pipes but failed.

The c program will need to get an input from the shell script. I am not sure to to read in an input from a shell script.

My bash script is below.

```
#!/usr/bash

# About on any errors
set -e

RUN_WITH_VALGRIND=""

if [ "$1" == "valgrind" ]; then
    RUN_WITH_VALGRIND="valgrind"
    echo "START TESTING WITH VALGRIND"
fi

$RUN_WITH_VALGRIND ./c_program

echo "Hello" | ./c_program
```

And my sample c program is here:

```
char str_input[16];
printf("Get input: ");
scanf("%s", str_input);
printf("Input [ %s ]\n", str_input);
```

I am trying to get the scanf to read the input from the shell script.

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: Why not simply pass an argument?

Comment: @H2CO3 I am trying to automate the process of getting inputs from the shell script.

Comment: I still don't see why simple command line arguments wouldn't suffice.

Comment: @H2CO3 There are many inputs I would have to enter and I just what to have a test script that will go through them and get them for me. I don't really want to spend time physically entering inputs as I have about 30 of them. I am trying to automate the process just for testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "Hello" | $RUN_WITH_VALGRIND ./c_program`, it's that simple.

But in your script, c_program will run twice as you re-call it after the `run_with_valgrind` call (I don't know if its intend or not)

Comment: Basically, I just want to run a test with arguments that will come from the shell script that will automate this. So for every scanf, the argument will come from the test script file. So rather than me physically inputting they will come from the shell script. Its not intended to re-call, I was just experimenting.

Comment: The solution I gave you will work. Separe each input with a '\n' or put everything in a file and run `$RUN_WITH_VALGRIND ./c_program < input_file`

Comment: There is one thing I am now having a problem with. I have about 30 inputs i.e. scanf's in my c program. For each input I cannot just re-call the program. echo "FirstInput" | ./c_program for the first. However, for the second scanf echo "SecondInput" | ./c_program will re-call the c_program for the second. Is it possible to do this without re-calling the program? Thanks.

Comment: `echo -e "first\nsecond\n" | ./c_program` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use 'here docs' for that:

```
$RUN_WITH_VALGRIND ./c_program <<EOF
first
second
EOF
```

cf. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html